# Jenkins Pipeline: I cannot add a variable from a concatenated command in bash script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have created several bash scripts that work perfect in the Linux shell, but when I try to incorporate them in a Jenkins Pipeline I get multiple errors, I attach an example of my Pipeline where I just want to show the value of my variables, the pipeline works fine except when I added in line 5 the environment, you can see that there are special characters that are not interpreted by Groovy as the Bash does.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label params.LABS == "any" ? "" : params.LABS 
    }
    environment{
        PORT_INSTANCE="${docker ps --format 'table {{ .Names }} \{{ .Ports }}' --filter expose=7000-8999/tcp | (read -r; printf "%s\n"; sort -k 3) | grep web | tail -1 | sed 's/.*0.0.0.0.0://g'|sed 's/->.*//g'}"
    }
    stages {
        stage('Setup parameters') {
            steps {
                script { 
                    properties([
                        parameters([
                            choice(
                                choices: ['LAB-2', 'LAB-3'], 
                                name: 'LABS'
                            ),
                            string(
                                defaultValue: 'cliente-1', 
                                name: 'INSTANCE_NAME', 
                                trim: true
                            ),
                            string(
                                defaultValue: '8888', 
                                name: 'PORT_NUMBER', 
                                trim: true
                            ),
                            string(
                                defaultValue: 'lab.domain.com', 
                                name: 'DOMAIN_NAME', 
                                trim: true
                            )
                        ])
                    ])
                }
                sh """
                  echo '${params.INSTANCE_NAME}'
                  echo '${params.PORT_NUMBER}'
                  echo '${params.DOMAIN_NAME}'
                  echo '${PORT_INSTANCE}
                """
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

I already tried the same thing from the sh section """ command """ and they throw the same errors.

Can someone help me to know how to run advanced commands that work in the linux shell (bash), that is, is there any way to migrate scripts from bash to Jenkins?

Thank you very much for your help ;)

I want to be able to create a variable from a bash script command from the Pipeline in Jenkins

PORT_INSTANCE="${docker ps --format 'table {{ .Names }} {{ .Ports }}' --filter expose=7000-8999/tcp | (read -r; printf "%s\n"; sort -k 3) | grep web | tail -1 | sed 's/.*0.0.0.0.0://g'|sed 's/->.*//g'}"

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can't execute a bash script in the environment step based on the  [documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#environment).

You can create a variable from a bash script using the [sh step](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script) with `returnStdout` set to `true`. Declarative pipeline doesn't allow you to assign the retrun value to a variable, so you will need to call `sh` inside a `script` like this:

```
stage('Calculate port') {
    steps {
        script {
            // When you don't use `def` in front of a variable, you implicitly create a global variable
            // This means that the variable will exist with a value, and can be used in any following line in your scipt 
            PORT_INSTANCE = sh returnStdout: true, script: "docker ps --format 'table {{ .Names }} \{{ .Ports }}' --filter expose=7000-8999/tcp | (read -r; printf \"%s\n\"; sort -k 3) | grep web | tail -1 | sed 's/.*0.0.0.0.0://g'|sed 's/->.*//g'"
            
            // Shell output will contain a new line character at the end, remove it 
            PORT_INSTANCE = PORT_INSTANCE.trim()
        }
    }
}
```

I would add a stage like this, as the first stage in my pipeline.

Note that I didn't run the same shell command as you when I was testing this, so my command may have issues like un-escaped quotes.

Comment: Hi @Vasiliki Siakka, thank you very much for the collaboration, it worked correctly, I just adjusted the command and that's it:

docker ps --format 'table {{ .Names }} \t {{ .Ports }}' --filter expose=7000-8999/tcp | sort -k 3 | grep web | tail -1 | sed 's/.*0.0.0.0.0://g'|sed 's/->.*//g'

Excellent!!! :)

Comment: That's great to hear!